# Android Studio limit number of lines in Java/Kotlin files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I needed to limit the number of lines of code written in all Java/Kotlin files in Android Studio. Is  there a plugin or a gradle dependency which shows warning or error maybe during building the code.

For eg. if I set the number of lines to 200, I should get a warning or error if any of the Java/Kotlin files in the project exceed 200 lines of code

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can create a custom lint rule that checks this for you.

Comment: You may find `Detekt` interesting for a static code analysing. It is highly customizable.  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10761-detekt